# SSIS job fails - Access denied to flat file

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-agent-job

I have created an SSIS package that reads a csv file from a network shared drive and imports the data into our table. The package works fine in the Visual studio. I imported the package to Integration Services Catalog and when I execute the package, it gives access denied to flat file error. What is required to run the package from Sql server, I created a job to run this package nightly and assigned a proxy for the job. Not sure what permissions I am missing, any help please

Comment: The account that runs the job needs access to the share. By default it will be whatever account is using to run the SQL Agent Service. I would recommend using a different account for each service.

Comment: How do I find out which account the sql server agent is running ? When I run the package directly from ssms integrations services also i am getting the same error, its running under my credentials, i have access to that folder. please help.

Comment: On the server look for a service called "SQL Server Agent", it will be the account that service is running as unless you're using a proxy.  If using a proxy, when setting up the job step and you selected that proxy in the "Run As" option on the job step, it would be that account that needs permissions.

Comment: I am using Prxoy and the principals the proxy is assigned to has permission to that network folder, when I look at the job history, it shows it ran as the service account id that has permissions to that network folder, not sure what I am missing

Comment: Got it work, found the right id that needed access and its working now, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

When SSIS packages are executed from SQL Server they access File System using the SQL Server Service Account `NT SERVICE\MSSQL$<Instance Name>` *(Where `<Instance Name>` should be replaced by the installed instance name)*.

Try running using a proxy account that has read/write permissions. Also, the service account must have these permissions on the data sources:

*SQL Server Serivce account Permissions:*

- [Configure File System Permissions for Database Engine Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-file-system-permissions-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-2017)

*Setting proxy account:*

- [Running a SSIS Package from SQL Server Agent Using a Proxy Account](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2163/running-a-ssis-package-from-sql-server-agent-using-a-proxy-account/)
- [Create a SQL Server Agent Proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-proxy)