# SQL Agent - Zipfile.ExtractToDirectory not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-agent-job

I have a SSIS package in which I have a script task. I have the below code, which is trying to unzip the file

```
 string subPath = Dts.Variables["User::ProcessingFolder"].Value.ToString();

 bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(subPath);

 if (!exists)
 System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subPath);

 string zipFilename = Dts.Variables["User::varProcessingFile"].Value.ToString();                

 string targetDirectory = subPath;
 ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipFilename, subPath);    

 Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

The above code works in Visual studio, but when run through the SQL Agent, the unzip is not happening.

How to fix this ?

Comment: do you get an error, if so what is that error?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are facing a permission issue, since when you run the package from Visual Studio it is executed by the current user but when it is executed from SQL agent it uses the SQL server service account.

In order to solve the issue, you have to grant the service account to access all needed directories or you have to execute package as proxy user:

- [SSIS job fails - Access denied to flat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58328263/ssis-job-fails-access-denied-to-flat-file/58348200#58348200)